# Downloads in Java program are sometimes corrupted

Tags: java, download, corrupt

i am trying to write a java program to backup a HTTP Directory on a remote server. The remote server is across several VPNs/Firewalls/whatever, so the connection is not always the best.

So i start by downloading the root directory listing and go through the entries recursively. It is a simple single-threaded program.

So my problem is, that sometimes the HTML i get is corrupted. Mainly it has multiple Null-Bytes over the whole document, which i can remove with a replaceAll.
But the other thing is, that it seems to have some text chunks two (or more?) times, so instead of "This is a text, please read me." i get something like "This is a teis is a xt, please read me.". If you cut out the duplicate "is is a ", it would be just fine. There are usually multiple of these duplicate texts over the whole document.

When i browse the directory with a browser (namely Firefox) i have no problems, everything seems fine. Just my downloader keeps getting corrupt data.

So here is my code snippet, which gets the HTML listing data:

```
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        if ("gzip".equals(con.getContentEncoding())) {
            is = new GZIPInputStream(is);
        }
        int x = 0;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        while ((x = is.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
            if (x > 0) {
                retval += new String(data);
            }
        }
```

Any ideas, what i am doing wrong?

Greetings!

Comment: is.read will read up 1024 bytes into your array, meaning that the buffer may contain old data. Take a look at [String(byte, int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20int,%20int)), which would allow you to specify the byte range to build the string

Comment: aaaahhhhh, i am so stupid! *big facepalm* ... Of course this was the cause. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace with this:
`retval += new String(data, 0, x);`

If you read less than `1024` and `1024` you read previously, you get the `x` + (`1024-x`) data being left over from previous loop

Comment: @MadProgrammer was a little bit faster, but yes, indeed, this was the cause. Thanks to you too! :)

Comment: @Julius Was on IPad, really hard to type a full answer ;)